# Devise Gem and the Geocoder Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using geocoder and the devise gem. And i am trying to get coupons near user's location

**Coupon Model**

```
def index
  if params[:search].present?
    @coupons = Coupon.near([user_long, user_lat], 50, :order => :distance)
  else
     @coupons = Coupon.all
  end
end
```

**Application Helper**

I have defined the user_long and user_lat

```
  def user_long
           current_user.longitude
   end


   def user_lat
           current_user.latitude
   end
```

**Devise Gem**

I have tried to use the devise gem helper to get the values like so

**Coupon Model**

```
def index
  if params[:search].present?
    @coupons = Coupon.near([current_user.longitude, current_user.latitude], 50, :order => :distance)
  else
     @coupons = Coupon.all
  end
end
```

I am hitting the walls and celling with this. Can someone help out, i know this is newbie question for but i can't solve it so save my life?

Comment: What is exactly happening currently?

Comment: @flooooo At the moment, nothing shows and there is no error on my logs.

Comment: @Benjamin  how did you get the current_user.lat and long? I have tried adding a after_validation :geocode to the :current_sign_in_ip but it doesnt seem to work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that i that i had the longitude before that latitude, It was taking away the logic

This works.

```
def index
     @coupons = Coupon.near([current_user.latitude, current_user.longitude], 50, :order => :distance)

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing anything on the index page because your @coupons array is empty:

```
@coupons = Coupon.near([current_user.longitude, current_user.latitude], 50, :order => :distance)
```

In development log (in the same window where rails server is running, if you are running the rails server from console), you should check out the SQL query generated for CouponsController#index action.

Assuming you defined your 'near' query like this:

```
class Coupon
   scope :near, lambda { |longitude, latitude| some logic...
end
```

You can debug this 'near' method using "rails console" like this:

```
rails console
> Coupon.near(10, 20)
```

etc..

Comment: Thanks for your help. Made me look at it again from a fresh eye. I used the console as you advised and i realised that my problem was the order or latitude and longitude.